# Set up DNS to find closest IP

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dyndns, failovercluster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geo-DNS providers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30567/geo-dns-providers)

I have one domain that may be accessed by people from all over the world. I would like to set up servers throughout the world and have people connect to the ip that's closest to them, even though they are all typing the same domain name.

What is this concept called and how does it work? Do I have to make special agreements with multiple DNS server providers? Anyone know any provider that offers this type of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question may be handy
[Geo-DNS providers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30567/geo-dns-providers)

Comment: Thankyou, that answers the question. The concept is called Geo DNS and  there are plenty of providers, such as http://www.geoscaling.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can rollout your own as well on bind using this patch http://www.caraytech.com/geodns/