# Choosing nearest Server across the globe?

Tags: hosting, routing

i want 3 dedicated servers: in USA, Europe and China. They all run exactly same website. I want to setup them so, that particular user will automatically talk to the nearest in network sense instance of my web site.

Which options do i have to make this work (I heard, Anycast is for that, what else )?
I need both a list of options and simple how-to or link, explaining the setup process.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris' answer is about DNS, so this one is about anycast :

[What is "anycast" and how is it helpful?](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful)

I find that anycast is more fault friendly that dns.

A bgp routing change will propagate more quickly than DNS entry.

So if a server become unreachable, removing the route to it will ensure that all traffic goes to one server.

Comment: Definitely, anycast. Many advantages, such as if you need to bring down a site for maintenance, just stop announcing the route.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very similar question here that'll probably be useful to you:

[Geo-DNS providers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30567/geo-dns-providers)