# Server Routing Nearest Location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing

I have a few VPS - same files and NGINX, PHP-FPM and stuff. How would I make it so that when the user goes to pingrglobe.com that they get redirected to the nearest server?

Thanks, Samuel.

Answer (score 3):

You would use [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) for this.

Comment: How would I do this please?

Comment: @LeSamAdmin Get yourself an ASN, a netblock from your LIR, a good book on BGP, and some routing gear.

Comment: Agreed...with the usual caveats about being careful with TCP-over-anycast.

Comment: Woah! I am on a VPS provider's hosting here and I got no idea what this stuff is! :/
I'm on DigitalOcean

Comment: Or, get a DNS provider that does geo-based DNS

Comment: Very good option as well, @MarkHenderson.

Answer (score 2):

AnyCast is a transparent way of doing this, as MDMarra suggests, and is pretty hardcore. It's a way of having a single IP address in multiple locations. This is akin to haing a single IP address in multiple worldwide locations and should work with pretty much everything.

Another way is to get a DNS provider that provides [geo-based DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/30567/geo-dns-providers). People from different regions will resolve a different IP address for your domain name. As a price point, [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/dns-hosts-comparison/) charge $55/month/domain (not sure how many records per domain you get), so $660/year. This will only work with services that use DNS resolution as a connection step (i.e. going directly to an IP address will still connect you to that region).

Another way of doing it is having your primary domain as a light-weight landing page, that compares the users IP address against a known list (like [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing)) and redirects them to `us.example.com` or `emea.example.com` or `apac.example.com`. This is an extra step and will only work for web browsers, or services that use HTTP and respect a 301 redirect.

Comment: This seems to be very hard! What would you recommend for a newbie to multi-location?

Comment: It is hard. It entirely depends on what you want to achieve, and what your goals are, and ultimately - whether or not you even need it. It's cool and nice to have, but ultimately there are very few people who actually need it.

Comment: @LeSamAdmin If it were easy, a lot of us wouldn't have jobs.